# How does BreezeJS will help in saving data to client browser without actually saving it to database

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

In SPA , how can we use BreezeJS to save data on client cache before saving back to database. I am working on this HotTowel Template and trying an application which is a simple calculator and I want to calculate the results using cache and save it to only cache (client browser), and I should be able to query on the results. ( I am already done with this type of application but problem is that it will do the saveChanges into database directly and the view is updated accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that you have a specific issue we can address.

For a general understanding of how to manage changes offline, you might watch John Papa's Pluralsight course, "[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 2](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)", particularly the "Saving State with Local Storage" module.

Comment: Yeah I m looking at brian-noyes course on Breeze I hope it will help.

Comment: I don't remember what Brian covered. Be sure to look at John's course as cited.

Comment: He covered BreezeJs here http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-single-page-applications-breeze